# Как происходит такой редирект в соседней вкладке?

Tags: javascript, html

При клике открывает новую вкладку и грузит сайт, как можно заменить на другой сайт ? Что бы при клике перебрасывало например на гугл

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 couponBox" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="copyToClipboard(&#39;#s10978&#39;,&#39;google&#39;,&#39;10978&#39;, &#39;https://ad.admitad.com/g/?ulp=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F&#39;)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="./index_files/shein.jpg" alt="" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <p>Expires: 2021-12-31</p>
      <h3 class="offerBox" style="cursor: pointer; text-transform:capitalize">get 20% off sitewide</h3>
      <p class="label label-info">Success Rate 36%</p>
      <p class="label label-success">Verified </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: А чем обычная ссылка не нравится?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
            
                            <div class="col-md-12 couponBox" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.location.href='https://www.google.com/';">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="./index_files/shein.jpg" alt="" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <p>Expires: 2021-12-31</p>
                                        <h3 class="offerBox" style="cursor: pointer; text-transform:capitalize">get 20% off sitewide</h3>
                                        <p class="label label-info">Success Rate 36%</p>
                    <p class="label label-success">Verified </p>
                </div>
```

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="color: #000 !important; text-decoration: none">
        <div class="col-md-12 couponBox" style="cursor:pointer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                   <img src="./index_files/shein.jpg" alt="" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <p>Expires: 2021-12-31</p>
                    <h3 class="offerBox" style="cursor: pointer; text-transform:capitalize">get 20% off sitewide</h3>
                    <p class="label label-info">Success Rate 36%</p>
                    <p class="label label-success">Verified </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @ОлесяСокол А, ок. Но почему все-таки не использовать a+href+blank?

Comment: как использовать ?

Comment: @ОлесяСокол Добавил код внизу.